# Failed to load the LayoutLib: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge

Tags: android

My ADT(Android Developer Tools ) was working fine and it was showing the graphical layout of all files few days back but today it is showing this " Failed to load the LayoutLib: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge "
All projects are running fine but i can't see the graphical layout of my .XML files.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you tell me how did you solve the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35980065/1318946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Restart IDE
- Restart a computer
- Try to update ADT, SDK and Eclipse Plugin
- If that will not help reinstall ADT, SDK and Eclipse Plugin

Answer (score 39):

Install a new API (upper than 14) and change the API, as below:

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me, because i was using the N developers preview. Just switched to API 23 and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This problem I have dealt with has be solved,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkEfd.png)

I install this IDE default option is API23.N, just change this option to solve it,for example, Choose Android API 21.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Classes With Identical names inside different projects.

I might know the issue. I just recreated a framework I made, and I called it number 2. A lot of the classes had the same name, and same method, inside packages of the same name. This seemed to really confuse the IDE and/or JRE.

I was able to sort of fix the problem, by making sure they weren't both being imported inside the same project! It is still giving me strange warnings, but it seems to be working correctly. What I would ultimately suggest if this is the case, would be to remove the duplicates from the project all together.