# Rendering Problems Failed to load the LayoutLib:

Tags: android, android-layout

Rendering Problems Failed to load the LayoutLib: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge (Details)

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: Failed to load the LayoutLib: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:166)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGQ1w.png)

Comment: find similar problem on link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933133/failed-to-load-the-layoutlib-com-android-layoutlib-bridge-bridge) but unable to find appropriate answer

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the API 23 version from layout??

Comment: yes i tested on API 22 ,API 21 ,API 19 also but unable to fix it

Comment: you might missing some libs. Check your `Standalone SDK Manager` and update your Android Studio to Canary - you would get AS 2.0 Beta, it may niot have this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35980065/1318946

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Layout preview rendering problems in android studio(Android Studio 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095839/layout-preview-rendering-problems-in-android-studioandroid-studio-1-2)

> Try changing your base application theme using below code - in *res/values/styles.xml*
>
> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
> </style>
> ```
>
> **OR**
>
> Also you can try Switching the preview's API level to lower one from
>   the preview configuration
>
> [image]

I think also updating your Android Studio to 2.0 Beta 2 by Canary channel might solve a problem.

If still doesn't work try to run your app on device - is layout here displaying properly?

You may also read this: [Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

EDIT: Check also solutions in these posts:

In this post [Failed to load the LayoutLib: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933133/failed-to-load-the-layoutlib-com-android-layoutlib-bridge-bridge) you would find:

> Possibly Classes With Identical names inside different projects.
>
> I might know the issue. I just recreated a framework I made, and I
>   called it number 2. A lot of the classes had the same name, and same
>   method, inside packages of the same name. This seemed to really
>   confuse the IDE and/or JRE.
>
> I was able to sort of fix the problem, by making sure they weren't
>   both being imported inside the same project! It is still giving me
>   strange warnings, but it seems to be working correctly. What I would
>   ultimately suggest if this is the case, would be to remove the
>   duplicates from the project all together.

Comment: I am using android studio 1.5.1 and i tested on API 22 ,API 21 ,API 19 also but unable to fix it let me check it after updating studio version 1.5.1 to 2.0

Comment: in the running device it work fine but on layout manager nothing appear

Comment: its not working on android studio 2.0 Beta 2 by Canary channel

Comment: if still doesn't work, try as often as possible a new Android Studio 2.0 (sorry I forgot the name) to refresh a layout on emulator

Comment: Worked: "Switching the preview's API level"  For me, I switched from Android N to "Android 6.0"

Comment: try to go to design mode and change api level

Answer (score 4):

I am using Android Studio 1.5,  and to solve this issue I change the API version from the default `API 23: Android N (preview)` to the `API 23 Android 6.0` as shown in the image below.

You might need to restart Android studio or not depending on your configurations.

Hope it helps!!

[image]

Comment: can't believe it but this helped :)