# XML Rendering errors Android preview N

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-n-preview

I have updated android SDK to android preview N after updating, I am getting this xml rendering error. After clicking on details it is showing following stack trace How to avoid this

[image: ?]

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:180)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:166)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:649)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: which API level you have selected for rendering design.. try selecting M only

Comment: I have selected API Level N but after selecting API Level M its working fine.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

This is bug in Android Studio.
Usually you get error: **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**

**WORKAROUND:** If you have installed Android N, change Android rendering version with older one and the problem will disappear.

**SOLUTION:** Install Android SDK Tools 25.1.3 (tools) or higher

[image]

Comment: Yeah I think there is some bug in API level N

Comment: Thanks! Maybe is related with the use of Open JDK in Android N

Comment: @KrishnaMeena This is bug in **Android SDK Tools**. You can check my updated answer with new solution.

Answer (score 11):

## NEW SOLUTION:

After Updating **Android SDK Tools 25.1.3** It will remove automatically that bug.

**Update your SDK Tools.**

[image]

## OLD SOLUTION:

I got same problem after updating sdk with [android-n-preview](/questions/tagged/android-n-preview)

[image]

I think there is some bug in **API level N**, I really appreciate the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917202/1318946) of [Ivo Stoyanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298241/ivo-stoyanov) but I found another solution that is:

First of all I have change **Android Version to use when Rendering layout in IDE** with **API 23: Android 6.0**

[image]

Now Error is gone away. I don't know exactly why but Now Its doesn't seems to me.

Thank you :)

Comment: I only have 23, and n, what do I need to do?

Comment: I tried it with 2.0.7, and still getting errors, it's not working, so I'm just going to switch back to stable as a non-administrator on windows.

Comment: I think by updating JDK7 to  JDK8 will also solve this problem.

Comment: I have installed JDK 8 before 2 days but no affected, Today I have installed Android SDK Tools and It works fine.

Answer (score 5):

It cause while rendering version is  **Andorid API 23: AndroidN(Preview)**. Need to change it [android-n](/questions/tagged/android-n). 
It is a [Issue 203683:  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203683)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar kind of error. I followed the steps mentioned above. I changed the preview version to older version and it worked.

[image: Screenshot for the same]