# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android Studio (Not code - the application)

Tags: android

Im getting an error in Android Studio:

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 82277
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readInt(ClassReader.java:2350)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.getAttributes(ClassReader.java:2201)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:565)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:184)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:77)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.convertClass(RenderClassLoader.java:151)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClass(RenderClassLoader.java:135)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFile(RenderClassLoader.java:116)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFile(ModuleClassLoader.java:341)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModule(ModuleClassLoader.java:245)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ModuleClassLoader.java:206)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:1867)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.parseClass(ViewLoader.java:562)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClass(ViewLoader.java:546)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClassSilently(ViewLoader.java:502)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadAndParseRClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:676)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.<init>(RenderTask.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:236)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.inflate(NlModel.java:345)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.updateModel(NlModel.java:406)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel$2.run(NlModel.java:259)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:267)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:282)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This happens when i want to Preview layouts in Android studio.

I just updated to 2.2.2.

This was working fine before i updated and when i try and change the Version used in the preview back to 23 from 25 it still doesnt work?
Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I would guess there is a bug in the 2.2.2 version.

Comment: But my colleague next to me did exactly the same thing and it works.... but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: did u turn off instant run and check??

Comment: Can't help more with that .. I would suggest to reinstall it (last solution...). You might have a settings that is conflicting with this version

Comment: i keep instant run off. i checked if it was enabled after the update and no it was not.... the main issue i have is i cannot preview any of my layouts

Comment: ok. Is everything upto date in sdk manager??

Comment: When i update my android studio 2.2.2 then i face same problem but when i update my SDK API level is 25 and Building tool is also 25.2.3 and then configure it and it's work fine

Comment: Update SDK manager, if issue persist invalidate caches and restart android studio. After this it will work i guess.

Comment: @Ramz i have done the updates to all the SDK's but the problem still persists

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914758/xml-rendering-errors-android-preview-n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same issue and I Proceeded with invalidating the cache located in File > Invalidate Caches, Restart

Comment: This hint helped me to avoid that exception in Preview window of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error and tried to run File > Invalidate Caches, Restart. It didn't work for me.

My layout preview wont show because I had an error in the layout file. To fix this, **try commenting out each of the component in the layout XML file one by one**. Keep trying till you find out which component is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on Android Studio 2.3 using SDK 25. 
So besides installing all the latest SDKs, I also went to *Preferences> Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK / SDK Tools * to upgrade all the items under *Support Repository*.

Then the rendering tool is back to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've solved it by turning off "instant run" option

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Turn off "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy"