# Android Studio Layout not able to Render in Design Tab

Tags: android, xml

The activity is running fine in the device but is not able to render in the design tab
it is showing 3 Render problems screenshots are below:
Correct dependencies are already added and the layout is able to inflate the data properly into screen
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monday" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tuesday" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wednesday" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm reviewing this post, but since I had the same issue recently, I think I can help. I believe that this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269663/android-studio-not-rendering-layout). If that solution does not work for you, let me know, and I give you an alternative solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio not rendering layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269663/android-studio-not-rendering-layout)

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this issue I have the same issue and try the solutions that mention in the comments and didn't work for me